# Display JSON into listview which has multiple json arrays

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

I am developing an react native app and i want to display json object containing an array .I want to know how display that data into listview .My problem is i wont able to display content for all the array ,it only displaying data for first array index and not and entire list of arrays

Below is my json which i am going to use:-

```
{
  "response": {
    "airlinedetails": [
      {
        "airlinecode": "9W",
        "airlinelogopath": "9W.png",
        "totalprice": "4478",
        "airlinename": "Jet Airways",
        "noofstops": "0",
        "nonstop": "Y",
        "airlineRecommend": "N",
        "noofflights": 6,
        "originaltp": "4449"
      },
      {
        "airlinecode": "SG",
        "airlinelogopath": "SG.png",
        "totalprice": "4511",
        "airlinename": "Spicejet",
        "noofstops": "0",
        "nonstop": "Y",
        "airlineRecommend": "N",
        "noofflights": 3,
        "originaltp": "4483"
      },      {
        "airlinecode": "UK",
        "airlinelogopath": "UK.png",
        "totalprice": "6319",
        "airlinename": "Vistara",
        "noofstops": "0",
        "nonstop": "Y",
        "airlineRecommend": "N",
        "noofflights": 1,
        "originaltp": "6280"
      },
      {
        "airlinecode": "AI",
        "airlinelogopath": "AI.png",
        "totalprice": "4499",
        "airlinename": "Air India",
        "noofstops": "0",
        "nonstop": "Y",
        "airlineRecommend": "N",
        "noofflights": 17,
        "originaltp": "4470"
      },
      {
        "airlinecode": "6E",
        "airlinelogopath": "6E.png",
        "totalprice": "4852",
        "airlinename": "Indigo Airlines",
        "noofstops": "0",
        "nonstop": "Y",
        "airlineRecommend": "N",
        "noofflights": 6,
        "originaltp": "4820"
      }`enter code here`
    ],





Tell me how to display it using map function as renderrow is called only once ,how to iterate through all those arrays of airlindetails. How to loop through JSON and print all the values and not just index 0 values of airlinedetails




This is my react native code ,i have add for loop to iterate through json but it doesnt work like expected as it iterate through only through first index


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ListView, Image, Text,AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import data from './flights.json';

export default class Navin extends Component {

constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
       rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
     });

      this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
    };
  }

  renderRow(record) {

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
     return (

      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.info}>

          <Text style={styles.items}>{record.airlinedetails[i].airlinecode}         </Text>
          <Text style={styles.address}>{record.airlinedetails[i].airlinecode}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.total}>
          <Text style={styles.date}>{record.airlinedetails[i].airlinecode}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.price}>${record.airlinedetails[i].airlinecode}   </Text>
        </View>
      </View>

       );
        continue;
  }      
    }
     render() {
      return (
       <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Flights</Text>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </View>
      );
     }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  title: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f1b29',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  row: {
    borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#feb401',
    borderColor: '#feaf12',
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
  },
  icon: {
    tintColor: '#fff',
    height: 22,
    width: 22,
  },
  info: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 25,
    paddingRight: 25,
  },
  items: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  address: {
    color: '#ccc',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  total: {
    width: 80,
  },
  date: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  price: {
    color: '#1cad61',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Navin', () => Navin);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke the `cloneWithRows` with the array and not an object.

`renderRow` will be invoked with each entry of your array -> you don't need to write a loop for that.

Instead of using `data` try following:

```
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data.response.airlinedetails),
```

Now you need to adapt your `renderRow` method like this:

```
renderRow(record) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.info}>
        <Text style={styles.items}>{record.airlinecode}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.address}>{record.airlinecode}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.total}>
        <Text style={styles.date}>{record.airlinecode}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.price}>${record.airlinecode}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I have two questions for the same scenario.What if I want to access airlinedetails array as well as another array called 'allflights' which are there in the same response.What should i do now  if the datasource is only one and want to aceess two things.I have already tried giving data.response and then tried to access that but it isnt working..please help..its imporatant.

Comment: @user3496134 do you need to display this 2 arrays in the same table/listview?
If yes, you need to merge both arrays!

Comment: Yeah..I want to use both arrays data in the same listview or simply in same list row ..What do you mean by merging two arrays?? can you give code example of how to do that..it would be more helpful..thanku in advance..please help...!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What changes do i need to make in the data source,please give code in terms of react native..as you gave me like  previous code explaining how to do that.

Comment: It doesnt have anything to do with react native.. if you dont know how to do such simple stuff, i cant help you anymore, sorry