# Rendering JSON Data without ListView?

Tags: json, react-native

I've been looking at other questions such as, [Display JSON into listview which has multiple json arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758395/display-json-into-listview-which-has-multiple-json-arrays), and I keeping running into the same problem. The error I am getting is: `evaluating 'instance.render()'` when trying to go to the profile page.

```
componentDidMount() {

  return fetch('http://www.example.com/React/user-list.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
      }, function() {
        // In this block you can do something with new state.
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }



  renderRow = (rowData) => {


      return(
         <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

            <Text> </Text>

            <Button
            style = {{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
            title="Click here to Logout" onPress={ this.logout } />
            <Text>{rowData.username}</Text>


         </View>
       );
     }
   }
```

My goal is to display data from the database without using ListView. Although, I was able to succeed in displaying them with ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) I believe it's much simpler and easier to work with, plus ListView have been depreciated.
Your code should look like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://www.example.com/React/user-list.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
      }, function() {
        // In this block you can do something with new state.
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={({row})=>row.id}
            renderItem={({rowData})=>this.renderRow(rowData)}

        />
    )
}
```

Hopefully this helps.